# Prevent page from scrolling when GWT DialogBox with glassEnabled is active

Tags: html, css, gwt, scroll

In my GWT application I use a DialogBox like this:

```
    DialogBox dialog = new DialogBox(autoHide, true);
    dialog.setText("Hello GWT DialogBox");
    dialog.setGlassEnabled(true);
    dialog.center();
    dialog.show();
```

My whole page is very long and it scrolls vertically.

This works fine, the dialog pops up and the rest of the page is darkened. When scrolling (with mouse wheel) **outside** the dialog box nothing happens, which is fine. But when scrolling **inside** of the dialog box, the whole page scrolls away including the dialog box itself. This feels very wrong.

It is even possible to use scrolling inside the dialog box to scroll the dialog box out of the visible area and then there is no way to scroll it back, because scrolling outside of the dialog box does not do anything.

How to prevent the page from scrolling when using the mouse wheel inside the dialog box?

Answer (score 0):

```
dialog.setModal(true);
```

might work. This discards all the events that do not affect the DialogBox, aka scroll that is affecting the underlying page.

**WAIT NEVER MIND, DOESN'T WORK**
The Page will still scroll if the mouse is within the DialogBox.

Found this though:

https://www.mail-archive.com/google-web-toolkit@googlegroups.com/msg62527.html

Might be useful.